# Define children in a view

Tags: android, xml, children

I have following XML code:

```
<ScrollView>
    <TextView />
    <TextView />
    <TextView />
    <Button />
</ScrollView>
```

Is it possible to give all the children of my ScrollView automatically the attribute "android:minHeight=XY"? The best solution would be an attribute for ScrollView but I think I have to write some java code for that, haven't I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need android:layout_width and android:layout_height in any case for all your Views. Only way you can avoid this, would be by defining a style and apply that style to all your TextViews and Button.

Comment: I know. The widths and heights are set already but I want a minHeight, too, because sometimes wrap_content is less then my 200dp minimum.

Comment: Well then you just have to add that minHeight to the style.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It isn't also possible to set the children elements' style, is it?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to ... automatically

*To do some thing automatically you need to code it ;)*

Actually android gives you two choices here, you can create your own ScrollView and use it in the layout like this:

```
<com.my.package.MyScrollView>
    <TextView />
    <TextView />
    <TextView />
    <Button />
</com.my.package.MyScrollView>
```

Or you can use [Android Styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html), to set a variable for your width, and it will be used in all the `ScrollView`.

Personally I recommend using the second method it sounds more native to Android.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<ScrollView minHeight="android:minHeight=XY">
    <TextView />
    <TextView />
    <TextView />
    <Button />
</ScrollView>
```

The code processing the XML should look for minHeight and apply it to the children appropriatly.

Comment: Hmmm ... I need actually android:minHeight="200dp" but minHeight="android:minHeight=200dp" and minHeight="android:minHeight="200dp"" don't work ...